# $(X,Y)$ has the following joint p.d.f $f_{X,Y} (x,y)= \dots $ , show that $ f_{X-Y} (u)= \dots $

Tags: probability-distributions

Q:

$(X,Y)$ has the following joint p.d.f $$f_{X,Y} (x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{2}{(1+x+y)^3}, \ &x,y > 0 \\ 0, \ &\text{elsewhere.} \end{cases}$$ Show that $$ f_{X-Y} (u)= \frac{1}{2(1+|u|)^2}, \ -\infty < v < \infty. $$

Attempted solution:

Using change-of-variables, $ \begin{cases} u = x-y \\ v= y \end{cases}$ gives the Jacobian $J = 1$. Hence $$f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X,Y}(u+v,v) = \begin{cases} \frac{2}{(1+u+2v)^3}, \ &v > 0  \ \land v > -u  \\ 0, \ &\text{elsewhere.} \end{cases}$$

The p.d.f for $f_{X-Y} = f_U $ is then

\begin{equation} \begin{split} &\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(1+u+2v)^3} dv, \ u >0 \\
 &\int_{-u}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(1+u+2v)^3} dv, \ u < 0\end{split} \end{equation}

I'm having trouble solving the integrals, which yields a feeling that I might've taken the wrong route to the solution. Any hints?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. Use that $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \frac{1}{(1+u+2 v)^2} =  \frac{-4}{(1+u+2 v)^3}.$$

Comment: @P.S.Dester Thank you, that sealed the deal.